# how to enlarge docker container size?

Tags: image, docker, resize

I need to create a big docker image with the following steps:

1. Create Dockerfile with the following info:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.202-bionic as build
ARG BUILDCONFIG=RELEASE
ARG VERSION=1.0.0

WORKDIR .
COPY . /build/
COPY Model/Model.sln /build/Model/

RUN dotnet build ./build/Model/Model.sln
RUN dotnet restore ./build/Model/Model.sln

WORKDIR /build/Model
RUN dotnet publish Model.sln -c $BUILDCONFIG -o out /p:Version=$VERSION
```

2. Build docker image with following command

```
$ docker build -t modelwithpr .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  27.39GB
Step 1/10 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.202-bionic as build
3.1.202-bionic: Pulling from dotnet/core/sdk
23884877105a: Pull complete 
bc38caa0f5b9: Pull complete 
2910811b6c42: Pull complete 
36505266dcc6: Pull complete 
21e3523d71cd: Pull complete 
3c423fdfc300: Pull complete 
3c953506ccad: Pull complete 
3b8b572de54f: Pull complete 
8f2eb870f86d: Pull complete 
e52b20b76b9c: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:9ee35c3d8395a15b21cc2eca5d66c8e7df62254c12ddb1249731c568458de124
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.202-bionic
 ---> 82688290b31f
Step 2/10 : ARG BUILDCONFIG=RELEASE
 ---> Running in 74f348453403
Removing intermediate container 74f348453403
 ---> f07df710b48e
Step 3/10 : ARG VERSION=1.0.0
 ---> Running in d1556dc14108
Removing intermediate container d1556dc14108
 ---> 63b311ef2174
Step 4/10 : WORKDIR .
 ---> Running in acd6a2b9f467
Removing intermediate container acd6a2b9f467
 ---> cecc23485351
Step 5/10 : COPY . /build/
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /build/Model/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll: no space left on device
```

I check the path Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data and find the Docker.raw file is 59GB(don't know why it's so big).

Is there a way to enlarge the container size?

Comment: seems like you are building docker image in some wrong context, better to create folder `docker-app` move everything to this folder that is required and build docker-image as current context is 27GB `Sending build context to Docker daemon  27.39GB`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I create the docker image from a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile info is uploaded in my original question. Do you have some suggestion about why the image size is doubled?

Comment: the dockerfile should not be such a big, just remove `COPY . /build/` this line for testing and the size will be less then 500MB

Comment: But this solution includes around 100 projects, I need to copy the source files to /build. Otherwise I'll get file/project not found issue.

Comment: why you need 100 project in single docker image? it should be then like `Copy ./projectA /build/`

Comment: or more generic `COPY ./${PROJECT} /build` then `docker build  --build-args PROJECT=projectA -t projects .`

Comment: The sln is kind of tricky. :)  I need all of the requested projects source files to build the sln, then run the binary file generated by this solution...

Comment: I see the multi-stage will work like charm. you end image will be small.